# How to generate Gamma random variables with known correlation coefficients

Tags: matlab, random, correlation, gamma-distribution

If I know the correlation coefficient between any two Gamma random variables `Xi` and `Xj` as `rho_ij`, I am wondering how I can generate the set of N Gamma distributed random numbers of `X1...XN` using MATLAB.

For example, my correlation coefficient matrix is

```
rho=[1.0 0.5 0.7; 
     0.5 1.0 0.4; 
     0.7 0.4 1.0]
```

Then, I need `X1`, `X2`, and `X3`.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by @PeterO and @pjs in the comments, correlation is only preserved under linear transformations. Since I apply a non linear transormation, the correlation between the variables do not correspond to the desired correlation.

This answer is not complete.

**Original Answer:**

Using `gaminv` you will be able to transform  multivariate normal random numbers into gamma one.

```
n   = 100;           % # of random number

mu  = [0,0,0];       % [muX1, muX2, muX3]

rho = [1.0 0.5 0.7; 
       0.5 1.0 0.4; 
       0.7 0.4 1.0]  % covariance matrix

Z = mvnrnd(mu, rho, n); %Generate multivariate corralated random number

U = normcdf(Z,0,1);     %Compute the CDF

%gamma distribution parameter 
a = 2
b = 1

%transform your normal multivariate number into gamma distribution with gaminv
X = [gaminv(U(:,1),a,b) gaminv(U(:,2),a,b) gaminv(U(:,3),a,b)];

% Variable extraction:
X1 = X(:,1);
X2 = ...
```

Result using only X1 and X2 and a covariance factor of 0.8:

[image]

Comment: Here, `U` holds three uniformly distributed, but correlated, random variables from a 3-dimensional _Gaussian copula_.

Comment: The problem with this is that both transformations in the chain N -> U -> G are non-linear, while correlation is only preserved under linear transformations.  The Gamma outcomes may be correlated, but not with the desired magnitudes.

Comment: @pjs Ho,... yes indeed, thank you. Any workaroung ? But then it should exist a function that could map `f(rho_normal) = rho_gamma` no ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know of any straightforward workarounds.

Comment: When I calculate `corrcoef(X)` for `n =10^5`, I got `[    1.0000    0.4692    0.6771;
    0.4692    1.0000    0.3704;    0.6771    0.3704    1.0000]`. And it was `[    1.0000    0.4743    0.6783;     0.4743    1.0000    0.3754;     0.6783    0.3754    1.0000]` for `n=10^7`. I am not sure that this is the way to check.